# Matching String pattern in java using predefined keywords

Tags: java, mapping, keyword-search

I am trying to match a string with keywords stored in a list. I receive a String input from an API call which I need to process and assign score. Below is an example of what of I am trying to achieve.

Input from API: *hewlett packard*

I have a keyword dictionary with matching keywords for all possible inputs. For eg:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

HP, Hewlett Packard, H Packard, Hewlett P, H P, Hewlett-Packard, Hewlett_Packard

Samsung, Samsung Inc, Samsung US

Amazon, Amazon US, Amazon Prime
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Currently, this keyword dictionary is stored in an excel file.

I plan to read this excel file to a list and then traverse through the entire map to find a matching entry. However, There may be entries which have hp(eg: HPSC Online) and it will get mapped to the wrong keyword(HP)

Can anyone let me know an alternate way to implement this in java OR if there is a library available that can help me achieve this.

Comment: The "logic" way would be to put "more specific" entries first. So "HPSC" should come before "HP", rhis way things related to "hpsc" will be assigned to the right keyword

Comment: This keyword file will be a running list and will be updated manually every time a new match is found. Also, the keyword list is huge and to be able to make sorted entries each time may not be a feasible option